# Rails index action - how to have a 'current row'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller

I am implementing something like facebook's messaging system as part of my Rails app (using Rails 4.0 with Ruby 2.0).  So imagine that the UI has two main columns, the left column is a list of conversations, and the larger right column is a list of messages for the current conversation.

The main action I have in my conversations controller is `index`.  However, I need for each of the conversations to be clickable, and receive a highlight when it is active.  So my route `GET /conversations` routes to the index method.  But how would I have a `GET /conversations/:id` route? ... That's normally for the show action.  Am having trouble architecting the controller.

UPDATE: as brought up in the answer by @Fellow Stranger below, yes, I have `resources conversations` in my routes.rb so that I have the 8 standard Rails 4 URI Patterns:

```
    messages GET    /conversations(.:format)             conversations#index
             POST   /conversations(.:format)             conversations#create
 new_message GET    /conversations/new(.:format)         conversations#new
edit_message GET    /conversations/:id/edit(.:format)    conversations#edit
     message GET    /conversations/:id(.:format)         conversations#show
             PATCH  /conversations/:id(.:format)         conversations#update
             PUT    /conversations/:id(.:format)         conversations#update
             DELETE /conversations/:id(.:format)         conversations#destroy
```

I.e., I have `conversations#show` available, but what should I do, have it set a session variable and then redirect to `index`?  That seems kind of absurd.

Comment: Just as Fellow Stranger mentioned, if it is just for highlight, the frontend techs, such as css and js, can handle this effect. There is no need to send a request to backend server to do the highlight task.

Comment: @SibevinWang, the larger right column is a list of messages for the current conversation, so when a conversation is clicked in the left column (again, picture facebook's UI), then all the messages for that conversation need to be populated into the larger right column, as well as the conversation being highlighted in the left hand column.

Comment: To fetch the messages of a particular conversation to the right col, I think it should handled by messages#index with a conversation id parameter. The highlight in the left col is still done by frontend.

Comment: I reply some details in an answer, take a look.

Answer (score 1):

The usage of the RESTful `index` is to get a list of resources, for your requirement:

To fetch the conversation list in the left column, use `conversations#index`.

To fetch the messages for a particular conversation in the right column, use `messages#index` with a conversation id.

When a conversation item is clicked, the item highlight effect should be done by frontend(css, js).

Comment: This sounds like the correct solution!  But how do you implement it?  I.e., how do you render a page when it requires two controller actions?

Comment: In this case, I would render whole page with conversations#index, use ajax to call messages#index and render messages in the left column DOM in the page. With this solution, you don't need to render conversation list each time when a conversation item is clicked.

Comment: If you really want to render conversation list and messages in the same request, I think conversations#show should be enough. It need prepare and render both the conversation list in the right column and the messages for a particular conversation in the left each time. (Maybe conversation_dialogs#show is more suitable because it handles two resources at the same time, not only for a single conversation.)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a restful design and use `resources :conversations` in your `routes.rb`, then you already have the `GET /conversations/:id`. (If not, just add `get "/conversations/:id", to: "conversations#show"` to your `routes.rb`).

I would assume that your question more regards the view layer.

You could either render the view with a page request and then add a `.current` class to the list item, e.g. [with the helper method `current_page?`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-current_page-3F).

Or (for a more facebook-like feeling) you could render the particular conversation via ajax and then update the list item's class with javascript at the same time you insert the conversation.